# Why can't Python access a subfunction from outside?

Tags: python

```
def A():
    def B():
        #do something

a = A()
a.B()
```

Why isn't the above (such simple code) possible in Python?  Is there a 'pythonic' (legible, unsurprising, non-hacky) workaround that does not turn A() into a class?

**Edit 1:** The above was explained to me that B is local to A, thus it only exists as long as A is being evaluated.  So if we make it global (and be sure not to have it overriden), then why doesn't this work?

```
def A():
    def B():
        #do something
    return A()

a = A()
a.B()
```

It says it's returning a 'NoneType' object.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because a function definition just creates a name in the local namespace.  What you are doing is no different than:

```
def f():
    a = 2
```

and then asking why you can't access `a` from outside the function.  Names bound inside a function are local to the function.

In addition, your proposed code is strange.  when you do `a = f()`, you are setting a to the *return value* of the function.  Your function returns nothing, so you can't hope to access anything through the return value.  It is possible to return the inner function directly:

```
def f():
   def g():
      return "blah"
   return g

>>> func = f()
>>> func()
'blah'
```

And this can indeed be useful.  But there isn't a generic way to access things inside the function from outside except by modifying global variables (which is usually a bad idea) or returning the values.  That's how functions work: they take inputs and return outputs; they don't make their innards available to the outside word.

Answer (score 6):

To call B with the syntax you want, use:

```
def A():
    def B():
        print("I'm B")
    A.B = B
    return A

a = A()
a.B()
A.B()
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is useless, since to initialize `A.B` it is necessary to call `A()` at least once. :(

Comment: @prokher it is necessary to call A to even create a nested function. And it will be a different function each time you call A. That's the only reason to have a nested function in the first place.

Comment: Not useless. You have to know where to use it! Thanks @panda-34.